# How to correctly insert utf-8 characters into a MySQL table using python

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8

I am extremely confused and puzzled by how I store strings with unusual characters (to someone who is used to dealing with a UK English character set) in them.

Here is my example.

I have this name: `Bientôt l'été`

This is how I created my table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    'my_id' INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    'my_name' TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`my_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Using this simplified python script I am trying to insert the string into a MySQL database and table:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb

mystring = "Bientôt l'été"

myinsert = [ { "name" : mystring.encode("utf-8").strip()[:65535], "id" : 1 } ]

con = None
con = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi');
cur = con.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO 'MyTable' ( 'my_id', 'my_name' ) VALUES ( %(id)s, %(name)s ) ; "
cur.executemany( sql, myinsert )
con.commit()
if con: con.close()
```

If I then try to read the name in the database it is stored as: `BientÃ´t l'Ã©tÃ©`

I want it to read: `Bientôt l'été`

How do I get the python script/MySQL database to do this?  I think this is something to do with the character set and how it is set but I can't find a simple web page that explains this without any technical jargon.  I've been struggling with this for hours!

I have looked at this and I see `character_set_server` is set as `latin1` but I don't know if this is the problem or how to change it:

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: as far as i know `u"string"` is how you specify a string in utf8 format

Comment: If this is Python 2, you do *not* need to call `encode()`. Only use that if `mystring` is a `unicode` object. Because you set the source code encoding to UTF8, your `mystring` is *already encoded*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did you try, this query `set names utf8;`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb

mystring = "Bientôt l'été"

myinsert = [{ "name": mystring.encode("utf-8").strip()[:65535], "id": 1 }]

con = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi');
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("set names utf8;")     # <--- add this line,

sql = "INSERT INTO 'MyTable' ( 'my_id', 'my_name' ) VALUES ( %(id)s, %(name)s ) ; "
cur.executemany( sql, myinsert )
con.commit()
if con: con.close()
```

Comment: Yes, that was my problem (along with a complete misunderstanding of character sets!).  I ended up using this `con.set_character_set('utf8') cur.execute('SET NAMES utf8;') cur.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;') cur.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')`

Answer (score 6):

Set the default client character set:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Change character set to utf8
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: working for me, the text row in the DB was set to something like latin1_swedish_ci and was returning null values, now it works.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is with how you *display* the data when you read it from the database. You are looking at UTF-8 data mis-interpreted as Latin 1.

```
>>> "Bient\xf4t l'\xe9t\xe9"
"Bientôt l'été"
>>> "Bient\xf4t l'\xe9t\xe9".encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
"BientÃ´t l'Ã©tÃ©"
```

The above encoded a `unicode` string to UTF-8, then misinterprets it as Latin 1 (ISO 8859-1), and the `ô` and `é` codepoints, which were encoded to two UTF-8 bytes each, are re-interpreted as two latin-1 code points each.

Since you are running Python 2, you shouldn't need to `.encode()` already encoded data. It'd be better if you inserted `unicode` objects instead; so you want to *decode* instead:

```
myinsert = [ { "name" : mystring.decode("utf-8").strip()[:65535], "id" : 1 } ]
```

By calling `.encode()` on the encoded data, you are asking Python to first *decode* the data (using the default encoding) so that it then can encode for you. If the default on your python has been changed to `latin1` you would see the same effect; UTF-8 data interpreted as Latin 1 before being re-encoded to Latin-1.

You may want to read up on Python and Unicode:

- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky

Comment: Martijn, this is Python 2.  How can I get the data to read back as Latin-1?  If I change the line to `myinsert = [ { "name" : u"Bientôt l'été", "id" : 1 } ]` and then look at the MySQL database it reads as `Bientôt l'été` which is what I want (except I want to do this for a variable string eg `mystring`).  Wouldn't this suggest its not a display problem?

Comment: @user1464409 Why don't you make `mystring` a `unicode` object in the first place: `mystring = u"Bientôt l'été"`

Comment: @user1464409: So you want to *decode* instead. The `.encode()` does not make sense, and could very well be the *cause* of your problem.

Comment: Janne, doing this does work but I don't know how to make `mystring` a unicode object.  I know I can do it with `mystring = u"help!"` but I don't know how to do this with when "help!" is obtained from another variable or dictionary for example.  I tried unicode() but this didn't seem to work and I don't know if this was the right thing to do or not.

Comment: @user1464409: see my answer, I added how to decode to `unicode` already.

Comment: Martijn, I tried to `.decode()` instead and I came up with this error when using another string: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2122' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)` when I tried this string: `Bookworm™ Adventures`.  It is clearly complaining about the "TM" character but I am really confused.

Comment: @user1464409: That's an *encode* error; are you printing the output of `.decode()`? Python then tries to encode the `unicode` object again to match your terminal, that doesn't always work. The *decode* worked.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to print it out, this is the error I am getting when I try to insert into the database.  I think I am destined never to understand this.

Comment: @user1464409: Ah, you need to read my answer more *closely*. I didn't say `.decode()`, I said `.decode('utf8')`..

Comment: I did read your answer closely, I was just abbreviating my response (sorry!).  I have just had a "Eureka!" moment though.  The answer is I also need to set the encoding being used in MySQLdb like this: `con.set_character_set('utf8')
cur.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
cur.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
cur.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')`

Comment: @user1464409: I was assuming you already had that set, since you claimed that `INSERT` for a `unicode` literal (`u'something'`) was working, but I now see that you only used ASCII codepoints in that value.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//Set Beginning of php code:
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

//then create the connection 
$CNN=mysql_connect("localhost","usr_urdu","123") or die('Unable to Connect');
$DB=mysql_select_db('db_urdu',$CNN)or die('Unable to select DB');
```