# How can I show arabic query search from MYSQL by JavaFX?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx, scenebuilder

```
SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE `name` LIKE "%شريف%"
```

Above query works fine and find the element by phpmyAdmin query but using it inside JavaFX doesn't get it.
And get the english searchs, So what I need to add in java to permit me search by Arabic.

Comment: which version of Java , JavaFx and scene builder are being used?

Comment: Java 8, and JavaFX & scene builder have been used

Comment: Few more questions, 1. how you store Arabic in DB ? By setting utf8_general_ci  for table columns ?  if yes, you need to set UTF8 encoding in your connection string too. 2. What issues you encounter? any exceptions or you just don't receive any results?  It seems a encoding - decoding issue, you can't directly work in Arabic.

Comment: Many thanks, I didn't set encoding in connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my above comments, I guess it to be a encoding - decoding issue of Java and has nothing specific to do with JavaFX and I also assume that you are not getting any exceptions. You have to use a proper standard while inserting as well as retrieving data. Helpful information is there at , [How to store arabic text in mysql database using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057913/how-to-store-arabic-text-in-mysql-database-using-python)

Refer this article to work only on bytes so your application is always properly internationalized , [Byte Encodings and Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html)

Refer this one too as how to set encoding in Java , [How can I insert arabic word to mysql database using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433293/how-can-i-insert-arabic-word-to-mysql-database-using-java)

Your console might be UTF8 enabled so you are able to match strings there and see Arabic characters.

Hope it helps.